# Applying different multipliers in COUNTIF depending on the text string and adding the results with one formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to Google Sheets and have a question that I can't seem to answer on the internet. Is it possible to combine counts of different text strings in one formula but use different multipliers depending on the text string bring counted?

The counts I am trying to combine are for the occurrences of the following text strings "YWC", "YDO", and "YF" in the same range.

The multipliers for each counted string are ("string:multiplier") "YWC:1", "YF:-1", and "YDO:-3".

I used `=COUNTIF(B8:BJ65,"YWC")` and it correctly added 1 for every occurrence of "YWC."

I then tried

```
=COUNTIF(B8:BJ65, "YWC")-
 COUNTIF(B8:BJ65, "YF")
```

which correctly added `1` for each occurrence of "YWC" and subtracted `1` for each occurrence of "YF".

I am now at an impasse because I don't know how to  subtract 3 for each "YDO" counted.

Is there a way to get a count based on a number that is not `1`?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? If you need more help, please share a spreadsheet with your input and desired output.

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GkDmmyC https://imgur.com/cxRH6xy This is the graph im currently working with. Its a little game iv been working on with some friends for a while and were moving out of play testing and game design and into trying to automate some of the systems. I'm trying to automatically calculate resource counts on the map (YWC meaning Yellow Wood Camp Thats why it adds one wood, and YF meaning Yellow Farm, that's why it "Costs" one wood) We thought it'd be fun to make the game in google sheets so wed have a game we could play that our school couldn't block haha.

Comment: Looks awesome. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a **multiply factor** to any of your terms:

```
=countif(B8:BJ65, "RWC")-COUNTIF(B8:BJ65, "RF")-3*COUNTIF(B8:BJ65, "YDO")
```